# Array of arrays of interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript

I can do this:

```
result: MyInterface[] = [{prop1: val, prop2: val}]
result2: MyInterface[] = [{prop1: val, prop2: val}]

totalResult = [
 this.result,
 this.result2
]
```

this gives me `[][]`, the question is how to merge this initialization into creation `result` and `reusult2` inside `totalResult` and telling that `totalResult` is array or arrays of `MyInterface` ?

Comment: Do you mean `totalResult: MyInterface[][] = ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
result: MyInterface[] = [{prop1: val, prop2: val}]
result2: MyInterface[] = [{prop1: val, prop2: val}]

totalResult = [
 ...this.result,
 ...this.result2
]
```

this will add all your item of result and result2 in one array

that's if you want a simple array, if you want an array of array just do it like this

```
totalResult.push(this.result);
totalResult.push(this.result2);
```

EDIT after comment :

if you want to avoid result and result 2 do it like this

```
totalResult : Array<MyInterface[]> = [[{prop1: val, prop2: val}], // result
[{prop1: val, prop2: val}]]; // result2
```

Comment: but how to initialize in one line with creation of totalresult, to avoid creating result and result2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the type for totalResult too, so that you will get clear picture.
you can do it like below. [ Array of Arrays of your interfaces ]

```
result: MyInterface[] = [{prop1: val, prop2: val}]
result2: MyInterface[] = [{prop1: val, prop2: val}]

totalResult: Array<MyInterface[]> = [];

this.totalResult.push(result);
this.totalResult.push(result2);
```

Comment: but how to initialize in one line with creation of totalresult, to avoid creating result and result2 ?